# Как с помощью Java вытянуть параметры из терминала?

Tags: java, terminal

Подскажите пожалуйста библиотеку, или какой-нибудь класс, который работает с терминалом. Есть папка с исполняемым питоновским скриптом, там же будет лежать java-файл. Скрипт вызывается в терминале, отрабатывает, передает определенные данные(например, хост)  вызывает этот джава-файл, который при открытии вытаскивает переданный хост и использует в  своем коде

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что Вы хотите, что бы можно было запустить некий скрипт, который скомпилирует java файл и запустит его?

Comment: скрипт пишет в консоль(терминал) данные в процессе выполнения, под конец дергает джава-файл, который после запуска работает с данными, которые написал скрипт в консоль

Comment: жава файл работать с данными не может. Его нужно скомилировать предварительно. Но Вам никто не мешает перенаправить данные, которые выводятся в консоль в файл (если только там не какой нибудь ncurse) и потом либо использовать этот файл в java коде, либо ручками распарсить этот файл и вытянуть нужные данные.

Comment: Запустить скрипт (как вы его называете). Подключиться к его стандартному вводу (см тему PIPE). Выводить в этот стандартный ввод подпроцесса и при необходимости дублировать в терминал. Когда весь вывод закончен ждать завершения подпроцесса. Если нужно передать какие-то параметры, то сделать это проще через параметры командной строки.

Comment: нужно что-то типа этого: http://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.13.php   только для Mac Os  и с учетом того, что данные,которые надо считать с консоли буду вводить не я, а скрипт.

Comment: Неужели не знакомы с техникой конвейеров? Вот немного теории http://citforum.ru/operating_systems/linux_pg/lpg_02.shtml Кое-что можно нагуглить по словам unix Конвейер, pipeline, перенаправление ввода-вывода. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80_(UNIX) https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/au-spunix_pipeviewer/ Все это применимо и к питону и к жаве.

Comment: каюсь,совершенно незнаком.ситуация такова,что программист я начинающий. и до этого месяца с линуксом и маком не работал вообще...а на стажировке дали задачку,потому тут спросил,чтобы понять куда двигаться(если я вас верно понял,вы предлагаете с помощью конвеера в определенный момент отправлять данные,которые выдает скрипт джавафайлу?

Comment: Это не ваш вопрос? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823052/stdout-from-python-to-stdin-java

Comment: Ваш вопрос на самом деле не совсем ясен. Если нужно передать пару-тройку (да даже 100500) параметров типа хоста, то логичнее и проще передать через командную строку. Вы когда запускаете программу, можете указать какие угодно параметры. Для получения этих параметров и предназначены аргументы функции main(arg[]). А если жаву-файл разработал кто-то другой таким образом, чтобы он принимал команды со стандартного ввода, то конечно разумнее использовать конвейер.

Comment: вот сейчас мне пояснили,что сразу в исполняемый джава файл будут передаваться параметры.тогда разложу массив args по элементам и буду вытягивать из него нужные параметры. попробую.большое спасибо за помощь и за конвееры.эти знания лишними уверен,не будут(хоть их исопльзование тут ине нужно)